# Notice: Array to String Conversion while taking form inputs using $_POST[]

Tags: php, forms

I have the form input like this. But it is showing

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\testpage\index.php on line 95

```
<form class='signupform' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars('".$_SERVER."'['PHP_SELF']);?'> method='post'>
```

I have seen many posts around here, but could not solve it.

Comment: can you add some more code?

Comment: `action=''` there, solved. Your use of that syntax is incorrect. Google that.

Comment: Variables in single quotes are literal. Try `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: okay. The file is index.php
    <?php
.....
..

echo "<html>
.....
...

<form class='signupform' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars('".$_SERVER."'['PHP_SELF']);?'> method='post'>

....

.....
</html>"

?>

Comment: You read my comment, link, and/or Fred-ii-'s comment, right?

Comment: Also the error message in the title of the article has nothing to do with the code you posted.. Although both are issues..

Comment: Bihan, welcome to Stack Overflow, it is useful to us and you not to add code to the comments but to **edit** your question and insert the code as Chris85 has done for you.

Comment: @chris85 I made an assumption the error message (`array to string conversion`)  was relating to the treatment of `$_SERVER` as a variable rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you all.
Yes chris85, I have read the link you shared. It had been a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
    <form class="signupform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
```

or

```
<form class="signupform" action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('".$_SERVER."'['PHP_SELF']);?'>
```

What you are doing is:

```
htmlspecialchars(subject)
```

but `subject` is made up of a jumble of string and variable references, so to start with the *Array* (`$_SERVER`) contains the element(s) you want to work on, which are denoted by the *key* in the square brackets (`['PHP_SELF']`). But what you have is a concatination `.` and a couple of quotes inbetween the two so what you are doing is

```
htmlspecialchars(array + quote + string  )
```

which is clearly and obviously invalid.

So to fix it, you remove the excess quote marks and remove the concatenations between the *array* and it's *key* indicator.

```
htmlspecialchars('".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

This is better but still not there yet, you now have to tidy up the other quotes as because your function doesn't contain *any* string (it's just the array variable you're working on here), you do not need **any** quotes in your code:

```
  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

So to wrap up a long post about a very small issue, you would correct with this replacement to your original code:

```
action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>'>
```

---

It is also worth noting that `PHP_SELF` can be easily abused and should not be used in this context, better to use another similar process such as `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

You **must** keep track of your open quotes and try and avoid mixing quotes. You should also keep track of properly closing your `PHP` code with `?>` as your original code you forgot the `>` so the HTML was being interpreted as `PHP` by the server.